# matrix inverse for sum of positive definite and diagonal matrice

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

do we have closed form for  $(P+D)^{-1}$, where $P$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $D$ is diagonal with positive diagonal elements?

Comment: I don't know if [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804402/inverse-of-a-sum-of-positive-definite-matrices) meets your needs.

Comment: unfortunately no :(

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? In what terms do you want to express the matrix $(P+D)^{-1}$?

Comment: the diagonal elements of $D$ are my optimization variables and $P$ is fixed and known, my objective functions involves this inverse, so i need something that does not require getting non defined inverses, something expressed in terms of $D^{-1}$ and $P^{-1}$ (known) ,

Comment: I don't think there is any closed-form formula. $(P+D)^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $P+D$, hence also a polynomial in $P^{-1}$ and $D^{-1}$. But the coefficients of this polynomial depend on the eigenvalues of $P+D$, and I don't think you can obtain that information by considering $P$ and $D$ separately.

Comment: @user1551 I thought there must be something neat about this. Because it seems very structured to me. $D$ is diagonal with positive elements and $P$ is positive definite. Can we have a relation ship between eigenvalues of $P+D$ and eigenvalues of $P$ and $D$?

Comment: @Alireza You have [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl's_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory), which give some bounds to the eigenvalues of $P+D$, but you can't infer the precise values of these eigenvalues from the spectra of $P$ and $D$.

Comment: @user1551 tnx, but Weyl's inequality is just a bound I wanted sth that includes all eigenvalues of matrices not just min/max

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2977195/2987